# Data model: Having separate table for a field vs having it as a column in the main table

Tags: mysql, database-design, enums, data-modeling, datamodel

We have a scenario where we want to store the 'status'(say of a 'user')

We want to impose restriction for the allowed values of 'user' status.

So we considered two alternatives:

1. Have 'status' as a column of enumeration type in the 'user' table
2. Have a separate table for 'status' and populate with the allowed values during DB initialisation and have it as foreign key in the 'user' table.

Can you suggest which is a better approach and why
Appreciate if references are shared on what is the best practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enum is less preferred. Do a separate table for statuses. With a separate table it will be easy to change or add statuses, add relative data (just add a new field in your status table if you ever need it in the future), easy to get a list of distinct statuses. You will also have an option to set a status field in the main table to be NULL or to set for some other value by default. You can reuse statuses in the other table.

If you have only 2 statuses, say 'active' and 'inactive', just use a BOOL(or TINYINT) field type in the main table.

Answer (score 1):

(There are many Q&A debating `ENUM` vs `TINYINT UNSIGNED` vs `VARCHAR(..)`.)

If the set of options is not likely to change often, then I vote for `ENUM`.

- Acts and feels like a human-readable string.
- 1 byte.  (I would not make an enum with 256+ options; not even more than, say, a dozen.)
- I would consider starting with option `"unknown"` instead of making the column nullable.  This is a crude way to deal with spelling errors in input.

`BOOL`:

- may have some hiccups; I avoid it.
- In the grand scheme of things, it usually does not save enough space to matter.
- I will consider using `SET` or `*INT` for a large number of boolean flags.

Any column (enum/tinyint/bool) with poor cardinality will not be useful alone in an index such as `INDEX(status)`.  OTOH, a composite index may be useful, such as `INDEX(status, create_date)`.

**ENUM examples**

Some enums encountered that have more than 2 options; you judge whether they are good or bad:

```
  Database             Column            ENUM
| mysql              | sql_data_access | enum('CONTAINS_SQL','NO_SQL','READS_SQL_DATA','MODIFIES_SQL_DATA') |
| mysql              | interval_field  | enum('YEAR','QUARTER','MONTH','DAY','HOUR','MINUTE','WEEK','SECOND |
| mysql              | ssl_type        | enum('','ANY','X509','SPECIFIED')                                  |
| performance_schema | TIMER_NAME      | enum('CYCLE','NANOSECOND','MICROSECOND','MILLISECOND','TICK')      |
| common_schema      | hint_type       | enum('step_into','step_over','step_out','run')                     |
| common_schema      | statement_type  | enum('sql','script','script,sql','unknown')                        |

| mworld             | Continent       | enum('Asia','Europe','North America','Africa','Oceania','Antarctic |
| try                | priority        | enum('LOW','NORMAL','HIGH','UBER')                                 |
| alerts             | Stage           | enum('DISCOVER','NOTIFY','ACK','CLEAR')                            |
| todo               | stage           | enum('unk','load','priming','running','stopping')                  |
| zip                | z_type          | enum('STANDARD','UNIQUE','','PO BOX ONLY','Community Post Office', |
```

Comment: Yes, I agree, except I am suspicious of any ENUM with more than 2 items.

Comment: @BillKarwin -- Hehe: note that the first bunch are from 'standard' tables.  (The last bunch were mine, or derived from Q&A on these forums.)